# C# Selenium how to finish a test early without quitting all running tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, bdd

I am trying to run a test that checks a user's capability to perform a specific action.  But in my steps I have a step that checks that the user was first able to reach the page.  If they were unable to reach the page be cause they are unauthorized (step passes), then I want to finish that test early, not moving on to the following steps as they would fail, and continue with my other selected tests.

The test logic looks something like this:

```
Given I navigate to "/Admin" page    
And I don't see the unauthorized page "false"    
Then I can perform action
```

I want it to perform steps 1 and 2 but in this case the user is not supposed to be authorized to access the Admin page so they would never be able to complete step 3 and therefore the test would fail anyway.  So I need to complete that test early in the case that they do see the unauthorized page.

Comment: `if(unauthorized) { //finish early... } else { //do other steps...}`. Or even better, if all users will perform steps one and two, then you could just do `if(authorized) { //step 3...}`

Comment: @tehbeardedone Should you make this an answer?  It seems like it should pretty well answer his question.

Comment: Possibly. I was waiting to hear back to see if he needed anything that was a little more in depth but it's been quiet so I never bothered adding an answer.